# Setting JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-home

I try to set `JAVA_HOME` variable on an ubuntu server. I get the Java path with this command 
which java

```
/usr/bin/java
```

I set the result in /etc/environment

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java"
```

When I try to run a mvn command I get this error

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/bin/java/bin/java
```

Comment: ``JAVA_HOME`` is not supposed to point to the executable binary but to the java installation directory.

Comment: Are you sure that  adding this address  "/usr/bin/java/bin"  to PATH also?

Answer (score 2):

You should not set `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/bin/java`, because that's just a symbolic link to the `java` executable, which points to where the real executable is.

`JAVA_HOME` should point to the Java installation directory, and not to the `java` executable (or a link to the executable).

Find out where your Java installation directory is and then set `JAVA_HOME` to that directory (and not to the `java` executable). If you installed Java using Ubuntu's package management system, then the Java home directory is probably one of the subdirectories in `/usr/lib/jvm`.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the Oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/):

```
export JAVA_HOME=jdk-install-location
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

You can add these lines into your `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.bashrc`), and then refresh using `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This is incorrect; `/usr/bin/java` is not the Java installation directory on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Jesper Yeah, I fixed it.